# numberOfItemsInSection func calling before viewdidload()

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, viewdidload

Here I am first retrieving an image from firebase then adding it to an locationImage array,which will be later added to collectionView.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var locationImage = [UIImage(named: "hawai"), UIImage(named: "mountain")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    retrieveData()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print(locationImage.count)
    return locationImage.count
}
func retrieveData(){
    let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

    let imageRef = storage.child("blue blurr.png")

    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: (1*1000*1000)) { (data, error) in
        if error == nil{

            let tempImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.locationImage.append(tempImage)
            print("HELLLLLOOOO WOOOOORRRLLLDDDD")
            print(self.locationImage.count)
        }
        else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return
}

}
```

**Here the retrieveData() function is calling before collectionView()**.Instead viewdidload should be called first,how can I do that,can someone help ?

Comment: reload collectionview inside retrieveData() function.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Set collectionView datasource in viewDidLoad after retrieve data. Don't set in storyboard

Comment: Remove Datasource and delegate from IB and set them inside retrieve data after loading your data. @Qazi Shahood

Comment: ViewDidLoad should definitely not be called first. This is expected behaviour. It runs asynchronously. You should pass the data before the controller is loaded...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the collectionView to be called before ViewDidLoad?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
}
```

But this shouldn't worry you, because if the array you are using to initialise the CollectionView is empty, it wouldn't matter if the call goes to the numberOfItemsInSection method.

What you require here is to call a reload after you have data in your locationImage. So right after your self.locationImage.append(tempImage), add:

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var locationImage = [UIImage(named: "hawai"), UIImage(named: "mountain")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    retrieveData()

    //Add these two line here remove delegate and datasource from storyborad
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print(locationImage.count)
    return locationImage.count
}
func retrieveData(){
    let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

    let imageRef = storage.child("blue blurr.png")

    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: (1*1000*1000)) { (data, error) in
        if error == nil{

            let tempImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.locationImage.append(tempImage)
            print("HELLLLLOOOO WOOOOORRRLLLDDDD")
            print(self.locationImage.count)
        }
        else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**100% working**

Where is your IBOutlet for `UICollectionView`?

```
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Set first IBOutlet & try this code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var locationImage = [UIImage(named: "hawai"), UIImage(named: "mountain")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
 //Add these two line here remove delegate and datasource from storyborad
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
retrieveData()
}


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

print(locationImage.count)
return locationImage.count
 }
 func retrieveData(){
let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

let imageRef = storage.child("blue blurr.png")

imageRef.data(withMaxSize: (1*1000*1000)) { (data, error) in
    if error == nil{

        let tempImage = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.locationImage.append(tempImage)
        print("HELLLLLOOOO WOOOOORRRLLLDDDD")
        print(self.locationImage.count)
    }
    else{
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
}
return
}
```

Answer (score -2):

a simple solution is that put sleep your function for some sec something like this

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    do {
        sleep(1)
    }
```

EDIT: formatted function

Comment: Never ever do that!!